# Add new record by getting session from previous page and transfer to another page by using a link in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is my registration page. That "0.0" is the time duration.

[image]

Image below is the output of my system. When you search a name, that name has a link.

*Note: You can search only the names that are registered, and you can only add new record if the search result cannot found the name you've entered.*

[image]

If you click that "Mark" link, the registration page should look like this.
[image]

That data should be saved on the database. As you can see, "Mark" had already a record, it should saved as a new record.
[image]

After clicking the submit button, the CL on call data should become 1(output of the website).

And also when you search the name "Mark" again, two result should displayed like this:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+---------------+------------------+--------------+
|     NAME        |       NUMBER        |     AGENT     |   DISPOSITION    |     DATE     |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------- ------------------ ---------------
|  Mark Fernandez |      98798412       |     admin     |      Inquiry     |March 14, 2014|
 ----------------- --------------------- --------------- ------------------ --------------
|  Mark Fernandez |      98798412       |     admin     |      Closed      |  May 27, 2014|
 ----------------- --------------------- --------------- ------------------ --------------
```

Here is my search page code. http://tempsend.com/E4E688E318

Comment: Why can't you pass some userid along with the link and retrieve user data from the db in the next page using the userid passed

Comment: Can you paste the link("Mark" link) mentioned above.

Comment: it runs only on LAN @Kapilgopinath